# BigQuery - Email Notification Configuration

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I have Google Cloud and BigQuery setup. I need to have push notification (Like Email) on specific event  / any database changes. I have Google compute engine (without any applications loaded yet)

Can someone give me directions on how can this be done? What application can be installed ? Or is it something BigQuery already has?

Comment: What kind of trigger are you looking to have? What specific event? changes?

Comment: E.g. I have Sales Table in Big query, In Case sale is going down by 10000 for specific date then send email to Sale Group alerting the action. Or In case User have reached limit of his highest purchase of the day and email notification needs to send it to the user.

Comment: @Mandar. I know this is an old post. If are a still in the same field, what solution did you implement.

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery doesn't currently have a notification system. You could set up an App Engine task that monitors it instead.

(feature request? https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list)

Comment: I know this is an old post. What is the best way to trigger email based on data changes as mentioned in the use case above.